# FLEX: getting a folder size

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

I'm triying to get a folder size by doing:

```
var FolderFile:File = new File("file:///SomePath/Folder");
var FolderSize: FolderFile.size;
```

But this gives me a value of 0, how can I get the folder size? is there anyway to do this?

Tranks

Comment: What do you expect the second line to do?

Comment: what do you mean by folder size.. is it the size of the folder like 10MB or the number of items in the folder??

Comment: Check your syntax - your second line should probably read var FolderSize:Number = FolderFile.size.

Comment: This is an AIR question (File being an AIR only Class), and .size **should** be returning a Number value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way to do it automagically. Getting the size of the directory is a complex and potentially painfully slow operation. There could be 10s of thousands of files in a directory, or a directory could be located on a (slow?) network, not to mention tape storage and similar scenarios.

The file systems themselves don't store directory size information, and the only way to know it is to calculate it file-by-file, there's no quick/easy shortcut. So, you will have to rely on the solution you posted above, and, yes, it is going to be slow.

Comment: Believe this chap. You can see the same limitation is on the OS itself - it takes winXP about 30 seconds to total up the size of my c:\windows folder.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time :). I'm going to use the solution I posted above.

Tranks again

Answer (score 1):

I want to know the size of the folder (like 10mb). Sorry for the second line, I write it wrong, it's:

```
 var Foldersize:Number = FolderFile.size;
```

I just made a new class wich executes this function:

```
        public function GetFolderSize(Source:Array):Number
    {
        var TotalSizeInteger:Number = new Number();
        for(var i:int = 0;i<Source.length;i++){
            if(Source[i].isDirectory){
                TotalSizeInteger +=   this.GetFoldersize(Source[i].getDirectoryListing());
            }
            else{
                TotalSizeInteger += Source[i].size;
            }
        }
        return TotalSizeInteger;
    }
```

In "Source" you pass the FolderFile.getDirectoryListing(), something like this:

```
 var CC:CustomClass = new CustomClass();
 var FolderSize:Number = CustomClass.GetFolderSize(FolderFile.getDirectoryListing());
```

But this is a very slow method, is there a more quick and easy way to know the folder size?

Sorry for my grammar, i'm just learning english.

Thanks