# How to get folder size in Adobe Air?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air, mxml

How to get folder size in Adobe Air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly simple using [`File.size`](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/net/FileReference.html#size). Just in case is confusing, folders in AIR are represented using the `File` class, which extends `FileReference`, thus the link to the `FileReference` documentation.

Comment: Do you have any documentation of using the "size" property on a folder?

Comment: There is no way to do it directly like files do. See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2056929/3058015

Answer (score 1):

**Recursive folder listings and contents processing**  
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Recursive_folder_listings_and_contents_processing-9410.html

...has sufficient sample code in it to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

my implementation is:

`public static function getFileSize(file:File):Number{
        var result:Number = 0;
        if(file == null || file.exists == false) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(file.isDirectory){
            var files:Array = file.getDirectoryListing();
            for each (var f:File in files) {
                if(f.isDirectory){
                    result += getFileSize(f);
                }else{
                    result += f.size;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return file.size;
        }
        return result;
    }`